# Trying to make my own RxJs observable

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I'm trying to convert an existing API to work with RxJS... fairly new to node, and very new to RxJs, so please bear with me.

I have an existing API (getNextMessage), that either blocks (asynchronously), or returns a new item or error via a node-style (err, val) callback, when the something becomes available.

so it looks something like:

getNextMessage(nodeStyleCompletionCallback);

You could think of getNextMessage like an http request, that completes in the future, when the server responds, but you do need to call getNextMessage again, once a message is received, to keep getting new items from the server.

So, in order to make it into an observable collection, I have to get RxJs to keep calling my getNextMessage function until the subscriber is disposed();

Basically, I'm trying to create my own RxJs observable collection.

The problems are:

1. I don't know how to make subscriber.dispose() kill the async.forever
2. I probably shouldn't be using async.forever in the first place
3. I'm not sure I should be even getting 'completed' for each message - shouldn't that be at the end of a sequence
4. I'd like to eventually remove the need for using fromNodeCallback, to have a first class RxJS observable
5. Clearly I'm a little confused.

Would love a bit of help, thanks!

Here is my existing code:

```
var Rx = require('rx');
var port = require('../lib/port');
var async = require('async');

function observableReceive(portName)
{
    var observerCallback;
    var listenPort = new port(portName);
    var disposed = false;

    var asyncReceive = function(asyncCallback)
    {
        listenPort.getNextMessage(
            function(error, json)
            {
                observerCallback(error, json);

                if (!disposed)
                    setImmediate(asyncCallback);
            }
        );
    }

    return function(outerCallback)
    {
        observerCallback = outerCallback;
        async.forever(asyncReceive);
    }
}

var receive = Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(observableReceive('rxtest'));
var source = receive();

var subscription = source.forEach(
    function (json)
    {
        console.log('receive completed: ' + JSON.stringify(json));
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log("receive failed: " + error.toString());
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');
        subscription.dispose();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So here's probably what I would do.

```
var Rx = require('Rx');

// This is just for kicks. You have your own getNextMessage to use. ;)
var getNextMessage = (function(){

  var i = 1;

  return function (callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      if (i > 10) {
        callback("lawdy lawd it's ova' ten, ya'll.");
      } else {
        callback(undefined, i++);
      }
    }, 5);
  };

}());

// This just makes an observable version of getNextMessage.
var nextMessageAsObservable = Rx.Observable.create(function (o) {
  getNextMessage(function (err, val) {
    if (err) {
      o.onError(err);
    } else {
      o.onNext(val);
      o.onCompleted(); 
    }
  });
});

// This repeats the call to getNextMessage as many times (11) as you want.
// "take" will cancel the subscription after receiving 11 items.
nextMessageAsObservable
  .repeat()
  .take(11)
  .subscribe(
    function (x)   { console.log('next', x);    },
    function (err) { console.log('error', err); },
    function ()    { console.log('done');       }
  );
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

I figured out half of it on my own as well, and kind of got it working, although i didn't get as far as getting rid of async.

Now I can build my own first class observables, it's a beautiful world.  This is a great example by the way - should go in the RxJs docs somewhere.

thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is over a year old, but I think a better solution for this would be to make use of recursive scheduling instead:

```
Rx.Observable.forever = function(next, scheduler) {
  scheduler = scheduler || Rx.Scheduler.default,
  //Internally wrap the the callback into an observable
  next = Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(next);    

  return Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
    var disposable = new Rx.SingleAssignmentDisposable(),
        hasState = false;
    disposable.setDisposable(scheduler.scheduleRecursiveWithState(null, 
      function(state, self) { 
        hasState && observer.onNext(state);
        hasState = false;  
        next().subscribe(function(x){
          hasState = true;
          self(x);
        }, observer.onError.bind(observer));

      }));

    return disposable;

  });

};
```

The idea here is that you can schedule new items once the previous one has completed. You call `next()` which invokes the passed in method and when it returns a value, you schedule the next item for invocation.

You can then use it like so:

```
Rx.Observable.forever(getNextMessage)
.take(11)
.subscribe(function(message) {
 console.log(message);
});
```

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7v84hamg/)